# Generating the Continuous Sequence of Number for Consecutive Positive Number in R

Tags: r, sequence

This is the Data

```
Diff= c(0.0,1.7,3.2,-0.7,-1.0,2.2,-2,-0.9)

s<- data.frame(Diff)
```

here as we can see we have two Columns `Diff` & `Expected_Seq`.
For the `Data Sequence given by Diff Column` Expected Sequence should be generated

```
    > s
  Diff Expected_Seq
1  0.0            0
2  1.7            1
3  3.2            2
4 -0.7            0
5 -1.0            0
6  2.2            1
7 -2.0            0
8 -0.9            0
```

Basically Value `Greater then 0` should generate a sequence of incremented value (1,2,3,4,5....) till the next is negative ...and So On

Comment: You need to sit down with some paper and scratch out the basic logic it would take and make an attempt at this. With a real try, then people will help. But the stacks are not a place for other people to do your work for you, it is a place to find and give guidance when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
Diff= c(0.0,1.7,3.2,-0.7,-1.0,2.2,-2,-0.9)
s <- data.frame(Diff)

# define indexes of subgroups of consecutive positive or negative numbers
RLE <- rle(Diff>=0)
RLE$values <- 1:length(RLE$values)
subgrps <- inverse.rle(RLE)

# aggregate by subgroups, create indexes or zero for each subgroup and add to the data.frame
s$Expected_Seq <- unlist(tapply(Diff,INDEX=subgrps,function(x) ifelse(x < 0,0,1:length(x))))

> s
  Diff Expected_Seq
1  0.0            1
2  1.7            2
3  3.2            3
4 -0.7            0
5 -1.0            0
6  2.2            1
7 -2.0            0
8 -0.9            0
```